# to replace NA value from results of zoo::rollmean

Tags: r

I am working with a data recently, part of it showed as followed.

```
    SID1A   day1    day2    pci TRTREG1C    ladcc
1   1000_00001  0   1   0   A   98
2   1000_00001  1   2   0   A   95
3   1000_00001  2   3   0   A   94
4   1000_00001  3   4   0   A   99
5   1000_00001  4   5   0   A   97
6   1000_00002  0   1   0   B   98
7   1000_00002  1   2   0   B   94
8   1000_00002  2   3   0   B   97
9   1000_00002  3   4   0   B   96
10  1000_00003  0   1   0   A   101
11  1000_00003  1   2   0   A   99
12  1000_00004  0   1   0   B   89
13  1000_00004  1   2   0   B   88
```

What I am trying to get is the roll mean of ladcc by SID1A by the width of 3. So I tried the function rollmean from zoo and expression from dplyr.

```
    dt <- dt %>% group_by(SID1A)%>% 
          mutate(adcc_av3 = rollmean(x=ladcc, min(3, length(ladcc)), partial = T, 
          na.pad = T, fill=NA, align = 'right'))
```

It gives me result as followed.

```
   SID1A    day1    day2    pci TRTREG1C    ladcc   adcc_av30
1   1000_00001  0   1   0   A   98  NA
2   1000_00001  1   2   0   A   95  NA
3   1000_00001  2   3   0   A   94  95.66666667
4   1000_00001  3   4   0   A   99  96
5   1000_00001  4   5   0   A   97  96.66666667
6   1000_00002  0   1   0   B   98  NA
7   1000_00002  1   2   0   B   94  NA
8   1000_00002  2   3   0   B   97  96.33333333
9   1000_00002  3   4   0   B   96  95.66666667
10  1000_00003  0   1   0   A   101 NA
11  1000_00003  1   2   0   A   99  100
12  1000_00004  0   1   0   B   89  NA
13  1000_00004  1   2   0   B   88  88.5
```

What I want from the result is

```
   SID1A    day1    day2    pci TRTREG1C    ladcc   adcc_av30
1   1000_00001  0   1   0   A   98  98
2   1000_00001  1   2   0   A   95  96.5
3   1000_00001  2   3   0   A   94  95.66666667
4   1000_00001  3   4   0   A   99  96
5   1000_00001  4   5   0   A   97  96.66666667
6   1000_00002  0   1   0   B   98  98
7   1000_00002  1   2   0   B   94  96
8   1000_00002  2   3   0   B   97  96.33333333
9   1000_00002  3   4   0   B   96  95.66666667
10  1000_00003  0   1   0   A   101 101
11  1000_00003  1   2   0   A   99  100
12  1000_00004  0   1   0   B   89  89
13  1000_00004  1   2   0   B   88  88.5
```

Which is `rollmean(ladcc, k = min(3, **number of rows before this row**))`, I tried  `rollmean(ladcc, k = min(3, day2))`, but it don't work and gave me error of "k <= n is not true". So the manipulation of data in dplyr is not performed row by row? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a way to deliver the result as I wanted. `rollmean` seems powerless here since the `width(k)` is not changeable among groups.
I used `pracma::movavg` and `dplyr`.
Here's the code:

```
adcc_final_temp1 <- adcc_final_temp1 %>% group_by(SID1A)%>% 
                    mutate(adcc_av30 = movavg(ladcc, min(30, length(ladcc)-1), type = 's'))
```

It's similar to the original one, just different function/package.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rollapplyr` with `partial = TRUE`

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, 3, mean, partial = TRUE)
transform(DF, avg = ave(ladcc, SID1A, FUN = roll))
```

giving:

```
        SID1A day1 day2 pci TRTREG1C ladcc       avg
1  1000_00001    0    1   0        A    98  98.00000
2  1000_00001    1    2   0        A    95  96.50000
3  1000_00001    2    3   0        A    94  95.66667
4  1000_00001    3    4   0        A    99  96.00000
5  1000_00001    4    5   0        A    97  96.66667
6  1000_00002    0    1   0        B    98  98.00000
7  1000_00002    1    2   0        B    94  96.00000
8  1000_00002    2    3   0        B    97  96.33333
9  1000_00002    3    4   0        B    96  95.66667
10 1000_00003    0    1   0        A   101 101.00000
11 1000_00003    1    2   0        A    99 100.00000
12 1000_00004    0    1   0        B    89  89.00000
13 1000_00004    1    2   0        B    88  88.50000
```

**Note:** The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "    SID1A   day1    day2    pci TRTREG1C    ladcc
1   1000_00001  0   1   0   A   98
2   1000_00001  1   2   0   A   95
3   1000_00001  2   3   0   A   94
4   1000_00001  3   4   0   A   99
5   1000_00001  4   5   0   A   97
6   1000_00002  0   1   0   B   98
7   1000_00002  1   2   0   B   94
8   1000_00002  2   3   0   B   97
9   1000_00002  3   4   0   B   96
10  1000_00003  0   1   0   A   101
11  1000_00003  1   2   0   A   99
12  1000_00004  0   1   0   B   89
13  1000_00004  1   2   0   B   88"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```